# Is it the hardbrick. Phone is not turning on neither by forcing it by pressing vol up,down and power button

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, hardware

I have flashed a stockrom downloaded from the internet from the given link to my qmobile z10 mtk6753, using SP flashtool
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=45sO&id=0B_Wm2RQP1PtfcnVpaG1oVmhPLTQ

and it was successfully flashed into the phone by a tick mark. after that the phone doesn't turned on by pressing the power button neither by forcing it to be in the selection of recovery or factory restore options by pressing vol up vol down n power. now what? is it hard bricked?
Not turning on. just black screen. no boot logo, no recover or factory reset etc nothing.

Now when ever i connect the phone with the pc. it doesn't recognize the phone despite all drivers have been installed already. and gives unknown device. when i opened the device manager it gives this "Unknown USB device(Device descripter request failed)". I have googled it and found some solution to this generic problem by changing the power options etc and all the solutions on the internet. but it remains the same.
Is there any solution to this problem is it the hard brick? if it is how can i overcome this problem.?
thanks in advance

Comment: I have nearly the same problem as you now. What is your status for now ? If you found any solutioins, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: Yup i was at the ebd of the tunnel.so i just give my phone in warrenty.they flashed the whole system again!